# matlab plots vertical lines when it's not in the data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot data in matlab that doesn't (as far as I can tell) contain vertical lines. However when I plot it I get lots of vertical lines. I'm guessing there's some little syntax thing that I don't know about but I can't find any similar questions.

```
>> whos t 
Name      Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

t         1x33715            269720  double

>> whos nascent_ts
Name            Size                   Bytes  Class     Attributes

nascent_ts      4x6x33715            6473280  double

plot(t,squeeze(squeeze(nascent_ts(1,1,:))))
```

Here is the plot:

[image: plot]

I've tried transposing both sides but that had no effect. I just can't see how this could even happen. Here's some more info about what's actually going into the plot.

```
>> tmp=squeeze(squeeze(nascent_ts(1,1,:)));
>> whos tmp
Name          Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

tmp       33715x1             269720  double
```

Comment: Knowing the size of your data isn't helpful. We would need to see the data itself. It's important to note that with `plot` matlab is just going to connect all points with a line so you're likely seeing "vertical lines" where a low value is connected to a high value. You can specify that you don't want connecting lines and instead want dot markers with plot `plot(data, '.')`

Comment: Do `numel(unique(t))` to see if you have repeated time steps, and `min(nascent_ts)`, `max(nascent_ts)` to see if an off scale high/low value is present in the data to plot.

Comment: Suever that's it thank you! (I feel really stupid now!). If you want to write it as an answer then I'll pick it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you Matt, your comment was useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "vertical lines" that you are seeing is simply the result of MATLAB's `plot` functionality connecting all of your data points with lines. The vertical lines are where you have a low-valued data point followed by a high value data point.

To get around this, you can either specify a non-line (marker-only) style to `plot`

```
plot(t,squeeze(squeeze(nascent_ts(1,1,:))), '.')
```

Or you can set the `LineStyle` property of your existing line object

```
h = plot(t,squeeze(squeeze(nascent_ts(1,1,:))));
set(h, 'LineStyle', 'none', 'Marker', '.')
```

Answer (score -4):

Just try change y-axis limits: `ylim([-0.5 1.5]);`

Comment: How does this answer the question?